# Category results by time of publish?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, simplepie

I'm using simplepie with codeigniter to fetch lots of feeds from multiple sites.
I want to category all results by time of publish.. Such as published in 5 minutes, 15 minutes, 30 minutes, 1 hours, 2 hours etc.. in same page!

Any idea how to do this?

Should I do for all those times own query and push those to view page or should I do it in view page inside foreach?

Code examples are very welcome as well! :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would build a model for getting the feeds with simple pie.
I would even categorize them in the model.
I would call the appropriate model function inside my controller and pass the data return bu that method to the view for displaying.

The only complex part is of course the model.

Comment: Thanks for opinion! Just testing to do it in view with strtotime function. (start_time, end_time and if publish time is in that range etc..) Works but i'm not happy with it... Next i'll start to test what you pointed there! Let you know if you're insterested? :)

Comment: Oh man that was easy!! WHERE published BETWEEN $start_date AND $end_date then just make as succested, own query for all those times! :) Thanks! :)